# Can i run multiple services in a docker container with the same user

Tags: docker

Im trying to implement three services (jenkins, sonar and bitbucket) in  the same docker container with the same user "sofact". Or do they need to be with a diferent user?

Comment: 1) Why not separated containers? Jenkins clusters or Sonar scanners should definitely be isolated from your VCS system. 2) yes, you can, but what specific issues are you having?

Comment: Im using DFS, so it's normal to implement these 3 services together.

Comment: Im just asking to know if there are a security problem if i run multiple services with the same user

Comment: Yes, there is, philosophically, but that's not going to stop them from running. And you can use Docker Compose or kubernetes pods to run multiple containers "together". I don't know what DFS means other than "depth first search"

Comment: And why the VCS should be isolated?

Comment: Because it's purpose is to store the code, not scan or build